# OpenGLES 2 without shaders

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Probably the title of this question sounds a bit off.

I'm trying to follow this tutorial http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial02/tutorial02.html 
it is for OpenGL 3.3 but I suppose that I can learn a lot from it. So I'm trying to translate it in OpenGLES 2.

The author, speaking about the function `glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);` says:

> In this tutorial we are not yet using any shader but the vertex
>   position we have loaded into the buffer is treated as vertex attribute
>   index 0 in the fixed function pipeline (which becomes active when
>   there is no shader bound). You must enable each vertex attribute or
>   else the data will not be accessible by the pipeline.

This is the first time that I try to use OpenGLES 2 without shaders. It is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as far as I know it is not possible to neglect shaders in OpenGL ES 2.0 Applications.
In contrast to OGL ES 1.1 the fixed function pipeline was removed.
That is why everything (fragment/vertex processing) has to be done by custom shaders.
Fur further details see:
[OpenGL ES Overview](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/OpenGL_ES_Overview)